# How can i print out each element of 2 arrays together?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, drupal, implode

Im trying to print out some duplicated data from my database on a drupal site.

I have a query this function which find the duplicates, and then implode the data, after merging the 2 arrays together.

```
function aktiv_styring_find_dub() {

  $result =db_query('SELECT `fornavn`, `efternavn`, COUNT(*) c FROM medlemmer GROUP BY `fornavn`, `efternavn` HAVING c > 1'); 

    while($row = db_fetch_array($result)){
    $fornavn[] = trim($row['fornavn']);
    $efternavn[] = trim($row['efternavn']);
    }

  $navn=array_merge($fornavn, $efternavn);

  dsm('Følgende dubletter blev fundet flere gange i databasen:');
  dsm(' ');
  dsm('Navn:');
  dsm(' ');
  drupal_set_message(implode(", ", $navn));
  dsm(' ');
}
```

I get the following output on my site:

```
Følgende dubletter blev fundet flere gange i databasen:

Navn:

Amr, Camilla, Camilla, Casper, Christian, Christina, Christina, Henrik, Ida Arendal, Jeanet, Johanne Lucie Skov, Jonas Bach, Line, Louise, Louise, Maria, Maria Helena, Maria Lykke, Martin, Mette, Mette, Morten, morten, Nanna, Nanna Mie, Natalie, Nishanth, Pernille, Peter, Rayan, Rikke Søholm, Sidsel Sinding, Simone, Victoria, Hajir, Kalborg, Løvendahl, Nielsen, Hansen, Andersen, Pedersen, Andersen, Jørgensen, Mikkelsen, Nielsen, Andersen, Jakobsen, Andersen, Nielsen, Jørgensen, Jensen, Rasmussen, Andersen, Andersen, Andreasen, Andersen, petersen, Thomsen, Larsen, Storm, Ganeshalingam, Larsen, Nielsen, Chabab, Andersen, Andersen, Hansen, Drøgemuller
```

Now what i what is both a first- and lastname and then it should be seperated with a comma. Something like:

```
Følgende dubletter blev fundet flere gange i databasen:

Navn:

Amr Hajir, Camilla Kalborg, Camilla Løvendal, etc...
```

Here is my MySQL Query Output:

```
fornavn efternavn   c
Amr Hajir   2
Camilla Kalborg 2
Camilla Løvendahl   2
Casper  Nielsen 2
Christian   Hansen  2
Christina   Andersen    2
Christina   Pedersen    2
Henrik  Andersen    2
Ida Arendal Jørgensen   2
Jeanet  Mikkelsen   2
Johanne Lucie Skov  Nielsen 2
Jonas Bach  Andersen    2
Line    Jakobsen    2
Louise  Andersen    2
Louise  Nielsen 5
Maria   Jørgensen   2
Maria Helena    Jensen  2
```

Comment: You should not be using mysql_query because it's deprecated. Also, you should try to do things the "Drupal way". Use EntityFieldQuery instead. Here's a useful Drupal page on [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the name and surname in one step and then implode:

```
$all = array();
while($row = db_fetch_array($result)){

    // Concatenate Name and Surname
    $all[] = trim($row['fornavn']) . " " . trim($row['efternavn']);

}

 drupal_set_message(implode(", ", $all));
```

Comment: Good to hear! If you can, vote this answer up :) Thanks!